# Purpose of React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This might be a really stupid question but I am writing my first project in React and am struggling to understand the purpose of setState hooks.

As far as I understand, the setState hook is used to set current values used in a component that is scoped to that component only, and does not persist if a page is reloaded for example, the value is simply held in memory until it is destroyed.

My question is, what is the difference between using setState() to store values and just simply declaring a let variable and updating it the regular way? Both methods just seem to be holding a non-persisting value scoped to that component. What is the difference?

Comment: PLease check this for better understanding https://www.seanmcp.com/articles/storing-data-in-state-vs-class-variable/

Comment: That last part, about "updating it the regular way" is the _entire_ reason why the library is called "React".  You _could_ update it that way and then update all the other variables that depend on the first, or you could let updates "react".  It's similar to Observable chains.

Comment: I think if you do that a re-render won't be triggered, that's at least one problem with that approach

Comment: Check this [link](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) out. Where Dan Abramov talks about states and how managing them works with react hook useEffect

Answer (score 1):

changes in the state automatically cause your app to re-render (in most cases), so typically you store data in a state that is being displayed and possibly changed throughout the app (a menu whose options can change based on previous selections, for example).

Comment: Ah ok. I previously used Angular, and keep forgetting that React doesn't have 2-way-data-binding. Would this be basically React's answer to the same problem?

Comment: @MarcusHorne Sort of it has that desired effect if implemented that way but that's not the states purpose. Which is as Devon F stated.

Answer (score 0):

React re-renders the new / updated state on an event occurance storing value into a variable wont trigger re-render and data is passed on form parent component to child component through props and a change in state can be reflected among all the parts.
For example we need to print 100 elements on a page if an element is modified or updated in any way this triggers re-render but using var if the variable is modified or updated this won't cause re-render where in data wont be updated.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**, even though the answer's not very long:

`setState` or `useState` is the key for React to subscribe to your component's state and update your components when necessary. Using `let` variables for storing app state means React will never get to know about state change and won't rerender and update your components.

#### A short overview of React

The core principle of React is that **your components, and consequentially your UI, are a function of your app's state**. When your app's state changes, **components "react" to this state change** and get updated. Here's a simple example:

```js
const CounterButton = () => {
  // Create a state variable for counting number of clicks
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  // Decide what the component looks like, as a function of this state
  return (
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
          Count: {count}
      </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<CounterButton />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This is a component that just creates a button that shows how many times it has been clicked. Now, the component needs to store information about how many times it has been clicked - this means that the clicks count is a part of this component's "state". That's what we get from `React.useState(0)` - a state variable whose initial value is 0, and a function that allows us to change the value. Whenever you call `setCount` with some value,  React gets to know that the `CounterButton` component's state has changed and thus the `CounterButton` component needs a rerender.

So in other words, React allows you to neatly and concisely **define what internal state a component requires** and **what the component looks like as a function of this internal state** (and external props). React does rest of the work - it manages the app's state, and whenever a piece of state changes anywhere in the app, React updates the components that depend on that. In other words, components "react" to data change.

#### To your question

If you use a simple `let` variable instead of `React.useState` in the above example, React will no longer get to know if the `count` variable has changed. `useState` is the key for React to "subscribe" to your component's state.

```jsx
const CounterButton = () => {
  // React will never get to know about this variable
  let count = 0;

  return (
      <button onClick={() => count++}>
          Count: {count}
      </button>
  );
};
```

In fact, for a functional component, `let` variables won't work in any case because while rendering a functional component, React internally runs the function. That would mean your `let` variable would be reset to its default value. The above reason is more relevant to class components. Using `let` variables to store component state is like hiding things from React - and that's not good because then there's no one else to rerender your component when component state changes :)

[This part of the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) is a bit relevant - it does not go into any details, though.